# Remove hidden controls

Tags: c#, winforms

At run time, I have to decide whether to display a bunch of controls or not.
I'm working on this form:
[My form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/211Dp.png)

In some cases, i would like to hide all controls but "Row font size" label, its Combobox and "Close" button. When doing so, i want to move the remaining components up and resize the main form so it looks nice.

As suggested in the comments, i tried to use FlowLayoutPanel with panels.
One panel for CheckedBoxList, One panel for each pair (label, Combobox) as i want to keep Labels and ComboBoxes in the same line.

With this solution, i have two issues:

1. More components to manage: I have to hide the panel now instead of other initial components
2. Auto-resize is not working any more: If I resize the main form, inner components doesn't change size any more.

Also, I looked at the TableLayoutPanel, and it doesn't look an option for me as i have different number of columns in each row. First row, I have only a CheckedBoxList and in the second row a have a label and a combobox...

Any suggestion to address this issue and keep the Auto-resize feature for all controls?

Comment: I know in WPF that controls use an enum of sorts to set visibility, one of the values being collapsed which does exactly what you need (hides it and doesn't leave extra space). Not sure what the equivalent of this would be in a winforms app though :/

Comment: So you tried the most obvious solution, a FlowLayoutPanel and ... what happened?  Did you even look through the toolbox to see what those controls do?  Spend an hour, come back when it doesn't work.

Comment: @HansPassant i used FlowLayoutPanel as suggested but i still have to use it properly. I edited my question to explain the issue

Comment: you can "merge" cells in the TableLayoutPanel by changing a child control's ColumnSpan property

Comment: @Slai Even though, if I hide all elements from one row in TableLayoutPanel, the row will remain there empty!!!

Comment: seems to be ok if you set the TableLayoutPanel row size to 0 pixels or AutoSize and hide the controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Winforms, it uses a grid kind of layout in the background. So you have to take control of the layout yourself. The easiest way to do this is to create a method called `RefreshLayout()` and call this method anytime you hide or show the button. So your condition will look like this:

```
if (condition)
{
    buttonDown.Hide();
    RefreshLayout();
}
```

In the `RefreshLayout()` method, you need to determine if the button is hidden or visible and then move all the controls below the button up or down by the button size. Also, you may want to change the height of the form itself. So it will look something like this:

```
public void RefreshLayout()
{
    int offset;

    if (buttonDown.Visible)
    {
        // The button is visible
        offset = buttonDown.Height;
    } 
    else
    {
        // The button is hidden
        offset = buttonDown.Height * -1;
    }

    // For each control under the button...

    control1.Location.Y = control1.Location.Y + offset;
    control2.Location.Y = control2.Location.Y + offset;
    // and so forth, for each control
}
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to use this suggestion if there few controls to move. I have a relatively complex form to maintain. i have edited the question

Comment: @Mhd - If you have a lot of controls, then just create a panel, move the controls into the panel, then just move the panel up or down. One control